# Pass Through Charging IC

Tags: power, batteries, circuit-design, battery-charging, lithium-ion

We have a circuit which charges a LiPo battery using a [MCP73831](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/microchip-technology/MCP73831T-2ACI-OT/964301) charging IC. We'd like to swap out this charging IC with one that supports pass through charging rather than using additional components. Are there any simpler charging IC's like the MCP73831 that support this ?

Answer (score 1):

I won't provide exact parts because that would be an offtopic here:
*Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.*

Instead, you can simply add just 3 small components - PMOSFET, diode & resistor to avoid changing the IC. You can refer to Microchip [AN1149](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/01149c.pdf) on the design.

You might also look for the ICs supporting Power Path technology. These might suit your needs but usually they require a bit more external components than a simple charger anyways. But they can offer some nice additional features. Take a look at [this document by Microchip](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/51746a.pdf) for examples.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using extra components but that AN1149 application mentioned a PMOSTEF which also included a good schottky diode. So this design only requires 2 extra hardware components, we can make that work. Thanks for that information !